# why does Xcode always use the method of the superclass rather than the subclass

Tags: objective-c, xcode, design-patterns, inheritance, factory-pattern

I'm using the factory pattern in objective-c, but for some reason it's never calling the method of the subclass.. I'll explain by code:

```
// MailBoxViewController.m -- file using the factory:
SearchWorker* searchWorker = [SearchWorkerFactory getSearchWorker:param];
// whenever I call this method, it's always the one belonging to SearchWorker, 
// rather than any of it's children classes, even if on breakpoint here, searchWorker
// is of class type AllSearchWorker
[searchWorker search:[searchParams objectForKey:@"query"] withDelegate:self withSnippedDelims:snippetDelims startWithDB:dbNum];


// searchWorkerFactory.m
#import "SearchWorkerFactory.h"
#import "SearchWorker.h"
#import "AllSearchWorker.h"    
@implementation SearchWorkerFactory    
+(id)getSearchWorker:(SearchWorkerType)syncType {        
    if (syncType == SearchWorkerTypeAll) {
        AllSearchWorker* searchWorker = [[AllSearchWorker alloc] init];
        return searchWorker;
    }
    return nil;
}    
@end


// SearchWorker.h
@interface SearchWorker : NSObject
-(void)search:(NSString *)query withDelegate:(id)delegate withSnippedDelims:(NSArray *)snippedDelims startWithDB:(int)dbIndex;    
@property (assign) volatile BOOL cancelled; // flag for when we cancel a search op
@property (nonatomic,readwrite,retain) NSOperationQueue *operationQueue;
@end

// SearchWorker.m
@implementation SearchWorker
..
-(void)search:(NSString *)query withDelegate:(id)delegate withSnippedDelims:(NSArray *)snippedDelims startWithDB:(int)dbIndex {
    [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException
                format:@"You must override %@ in a subclass", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)];
}
@end


// AllSearchWorker.h
@interface AllSearchWorker : SearchWorker
-(void)search:(NSString *)query withDelegate:(id)delegate withSnippetDelims:(NSArray *)snippetDelims startWithDB:(int)dbIndex; 
@end

// AllSearchWorker.m
@implementation AllSearchWorker 
..
- (void)search:(NSString*)query withDelegate:(id)delegate withSnippetDelims:(NSArray *)snippetDelims startWithDB:(int)dbIndex {
    // implementation
}
@end
```

so I always get the error message:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'You must override
>   search:withDelegate:withSnippedDelims:startWithDB: in a subclass'
>   *** First throw call stack:

any idea why this is happening? also if i control click on the method `search:withDelegate:withSnippedDelims:startWithDB`, xcode jumps immediately to `SearchWorker.m` (ie it does't give me a list of files where this method exists).. and If i delete that method from `SearchWorker.m`, it complains that this method doesn't exist.. ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are two different methods. You have used `snipped` in the superClass and `snippet` in the subClass

```
-(void)search:(NSString *)query withDelegate:(id)delegate withSnippetDelims:(NSArray *)snippetDelims startWithDB:(int)dbIndex; 
                                                                    ^

-(void)search:(NSString *)query withDelegate:(id)delegate withSnippedDelims:(NSArray *)snippedDelims startWithDB:(int)dbIndex {
                                                                    ^
```

Comment: gosh.. someone please punch me!